# Citation Style Language (CSL): Find style by scheme

Tags: quarto, citations, csl

I want to set up an environment for scientific writing in [Quarto](https://quarto.org/). My question is: How do I find a citation style out of the comprehensive [CSL](https://citationstyles.org/) options that represents a given scheme? I want the references for scientific papers to look like this:

*AuthorSurname, AuthorFirstname (Year): Article Title, in: Journal Title, Issue, Number, Pages.*

Most citation styles that I find do not put the year between brackets but separate from author names by comma. Also, in most cases, there is a dot between year and article title, not a colon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "[Search by Example](https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/)" tool of the visual CSL editor to identify similar/identical styles to a pattern. Make sure you use the example metadata given on the left for your scheme.

If you can't find what you need, [you can request a style from CSL](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/REQUESTING.md#requesting-csl-styles), though note that the volunteers working on this typically only do styles for journals, publishers, or major style guides for free.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. I didn't find a perfect match so far and instead of requesting a style like you proposed, I will take a copy of the .csl file of the best match and try to modify the details myself.